# Fetch records from table with value but not b

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my table structure , I am trying to get the UUID with status only as 'error' but no 'ok'.

I am doing something like this

```
select UUID from table where status='error'
MINUS
select UUID from table where status ='ok'
```

Is there a better way to doing this.

| UUID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 3aa0a4ed-fa9f-472d-a208-8173288880ee | error |
| 3aa0a4ed-fa9f-472d-a208-8173288880ee | ok |
| d7d76644-d8ce-4c5a-af42-6bc021fd264a | error |
| d7d76644-d8ce-4c5a-af42-6bc021fd264a | ok |
| 082324d0-24a6-47ca-9b55-94fad628903e | error |
| 082324d0-24a6-47ca-9b55-94fad628903e | error |
| 3aa0a4ed-fa9f-472d-a208-8173288880ee | error |
| 3aa0a4ed-fa9f-472d-a208-8173288880ee | error |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS (<subquery>)`. For example:

```
select uuid
from my_table a
where status = 'error'
  and not exists (
    select 1 from my_table b where b.uuid = a.uuid and b.status = 'ok'
  )
```

Or, you can use an anti-join:

```
select uuid
from my_table a
left join my_table b on b.uuid = a.uuid and b.status = 'ok'
where status = 'error'
  and b.uuid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two statuses, you may use aggregation with one table scan:

> ```
> select uuid
> from a
> group by uuid
> having min(status) = max(status)
>   and min(status) = 'error'
> ```
>
> ```
> | UUID                                 |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 082324d0-24a6-47ca-9b55-94fad628903e |
> ```

Or with conditional aggregation that may be extended to more statuses:

> ```
> select uuid
> from a
> group by uuid
> having count(decode(status, 'error', 1)) > 0 /*Has 'error' status*/
>   and count(nullif(status, 'error')) = 0 /*And has no other statuses*/
> ```
>
> ```
> | UUID                                 |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 082324d0-24a6-47ca-9b55-94fad628903e |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=372af841cb80f2577f93dd328d73067f)*

Answer (score 1):

Best approach (in terms of performance) would be to use analytical function.

```
SELECT UUID FROM (
  SELECT t.UUID UUID,
      t.status status,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY UUID ORDER BY status DESC) status_rnk
  FROM  table t)
WHERE status = 'error' AND status_rnk = 1;
```